# Calling push() on array, TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Working in React Native. I'm trying to declare an array and then push things to said array, but I'm getting the error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`

**CONTEXT:**

The app prints via a thermal printer.

1. The `print` method receives an array of commands

Example:

```
print([{appendText: "blah"}, {
  appendCutPaper: StarPRNT.CutPaperAction.PartialCutWithFeed,
}]
```

2. The `print` method is asynchronous and if you attempt to call the method again before the last call has finished, it errors.
3. Because of #2, we created a queue system that accepts a job (array of commands) and then works through the jobs synchronously.

In a React component, I'm attempting to create a job by declaring an empty array named `printJob`
and then pushing various commands to it. In this case, we take a snapshot of a View and then push the commands returned by the `printImage` method to the `printJob` array.

```
onClick={() => {
  const printJob = []
  viewShot.current
    .capture()
    .then((uri) => {
      printJob.push(...printImage(uri))
    })
    .catch((err) => alert(err))

  newPrintJob(printJob)
}
```

`printImage` returns the array of commands to print an image and cut the paper:

```
const CUT_PAPER = {
  appendCutPaper: StarPRNT.CutPaperAction.PartialCutWithFeed,
}

export function printImage(uri) {
  return [{ appendBitmap: uri }, CUT_PAPER]
}
```

So the goal is to generate the array of commands and pass that to the queue as a job. Now, I could just do `newPrintJob(printImage(uri))` in the above case, which works completely fine. However, there is a particular setting the user can configure where it will need to print multiple images, one per ticket (in other words, multiple `printImage`s). I want to consider all of that one job, hence the need to create the printJob array.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I'm getting an error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property` which seems to be triggered by `printJob.push(...printImage(uri))`. If I comment that line out, the error doesn't get thrown.

I don't understand why this would happen because you can call push on an array, even if it's declared as a constant. I also tried declaring it with `var` and `let` and still received the same error.

I hope I've provided enough context here. LMK if I need to add more.

**Additional info:**

```
"react": "16.13.1"
"react-native": "~0.63.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was not pushing to the array. The issue was was trying to add the job to the queue:

`newPrintJob(printJob)`

...***outside*** of the async's callback. Solution was to move the `newPrintJob` line into the `.then` block.